# Filtering content by checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I can't find how to filter divs on its owns content with jQuery. My goal is:

- Get src value of image inside each divs with class .ticket
- Create checkboxes with that values
- If user checks chechkbox with value for example "img/delta.png" it should hide every divs with class .ticket except that contains image with same src.
- Unchecking checkbox again show all .ticket divs again

I have first two step but I stuck on that. Please use my variable yy.

Here is html code:

```
<div class="filter">
  <h2>Filtering:</h2>
</div>

<div id="ticketsX" class="active">
  <div class="ticket wifi">
    <h2>Delta</h2>
    <img class="airline-logo" src="img/delta.png" />
  </div> 

  <div class="ticket wifi">
    <h2>American Airlines</h2>
    <img class="airline-logo" src="img/american-airlines.png" />
  </div> 

  <div class="ticket wifi">
    <h2>American Airlines</h2>
    <img class="airline-logo" src="img/american-airlines.png" />
  </div> 

</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
$("#ticketsX").find(".ticket img").each(function () {
        var yy = ($(this).attr('src')),
            sections = $('.ticket');



        if (!$('input[value="' + yy + '"]').length) {
            $(".filter").append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + yy + '">' + yy + ' (<span>1</span>) </    label>');
        } else {
            var currentCount = $('input[value="' + yy + '"]').next('span');
            var newCount = parseInt(currentCount.text()) + 1;
            currentCount.text(newCount);
        }


        function updateContentVisibility() {
            var checked = $(".filter :checkbox:checked");
            if (checked.length) {
                sections.hide();
                checked.each(function () {
                    $("." + $(this).val());
                });
            } else {
                sections.show();
            }
        }

        $(".filter :checkbox").click(updateContentVisibility);
        updateContentVisibility();

    });
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzPGKQ?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic was a little weird and using some better selectors, you can do a few more things.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/305ww469/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var images = $("#ticketsX .airline-logo");
  var airlines = images.map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("src");
  });
  var unique = [];
  $.each(airlines, function(k, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v, unique) === -1) unique.push(v);
  });
  airlines = unique;

  $.each(airlines, function(k, v) {
    var filtLabel = $("<label>");
    var filtInput = $("<input>", {
      type: "checkbox",
      value: v
    }).change(function() {
      var self = $(this);
      if (self.is(":checked")) {
        console.log("Info: " + self.val() + " checked. Hiding others.");
        $("img.airline-logo[src!='" + self.val() + "']").closest(".ticket").hide();
      } else {
        console.log("Info: " + self.val() + " unchecked. Showing others.");
        $("img.airline-logo[src!='" + self.val() + "']").closest(".ticket").show();
      }
    });
    var filtLength = $("#ticketsX .ticket img[src='" + v + "']").length;
    var filtSpan = $("<span>");
    filtSpan.html("(" + filtLength + ")");
    filtLabel.append(filtInput).append(v + " ").append(filtSpan);
    $(".filter").append(filtLabel);
  });
});
```

First, wait for the page to load. Then collect all the images into an array. I can then iterate each and make an array of the source data. I then flush it into an array of unique values for the filter list.

**Note** At this point, you could swap them to Airline Names versus the image source values.

Now we make the Filter list. We know there is a Label, a Checkbox, and a count. I make new elements from the array and then appends them as needed.

For the Checkbox, I add a `change` event function that is bound to each elements. It checks the status of of the checkbox and hides/show the other items that are not this option.

A bit of a bug, if you check both, they are all hidden. To fix this, can make a function that looks for `$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")` and iterate over the values, making all those shown.

**UPDATE**

New Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/305ww469/3/

This handles all checked vs all unchecked better.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var images = $("#ticketsX .airline-logo");
  var airlines = images.map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("src");
  });
  var unique = [];
  $.each(airlines, function(k, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v, unique) === -1) unique.push(v);
  });
  airlines = unique;

  function showChecked() {
    $(".filter input[type='checkbox']").each(function(k, v) {
      if ($(v).is(":checked")) {
        $("#ticketsX .airline-logo[src='" + $(v).val() + "']").closest(".ticket").show();
      } else {
        $("#ticketsX .airline-logo[src='" + $(v).val() + "']").closest(".ticket").hide();
      }
    });
    if ($(".filter input[type='checkbox']:checked").length === 0) {
      $("#ticketsX .ticket").show();
    }
  }

  $.each(airlines, function(k, v) {
    var filtLabel = $("<label>");
    var filtInput = $("<input>", {
      type: "checkbox",
      value: v
    }).change(showChecked);
    var filtLength = $("#ticketsX .ticket img[src='" + v + "']").length;
    var filtSpan = $("<span>");
    filtSpan.html("(" + filtLength + ")");
    filtLabel.append(filtInput).append(v + " ").append(filtSpan);
    $(".filter").append(filtLabel);
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Your post gave me a lot. Just tell me what is that (k, v) in function(k, v)?

What that makes in our function?

Comment: @ZcelaAnonymní Please review: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ So when you see `$.each(airlines, function(k, v){});` I am using an unnamed function with inputs `k` for Keys and `v` for Values. In this example, `k` will be each array index `0,1,...n`. `v` will be the element in the array: `'img/american-airlines.png','img/american-airlines.png',...` Similar to `$("#ticketsX").find(".ticket img").each(function (){});` that you had used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using attribute selector:

```
checked.each(function () {              
    $(".airline-logo[src='" + $(this).val()  + "']").closest('.ticket').show();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJYaqm?editors=1010)**</kbd>